# HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("<h1>hello world</h1>") onGet handler method throw Exception in asp.net core 6 webapp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

```
HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(<h1>hello world</h1>") onGet handler method throws Exception in asp.net core 6 webapp
```

1. Create asp.net core web app in asp.net 6
2. Update the "OnGet" handler method of Index.cshtml.cs file with below code

```
     HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("<h1>hello world</h1>")
```

3. Run the application and observe the console window for error.

```
Code Details
-------------
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace ResponserWrite.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("<h1>hello world</h1>");
        }
    }
}
```

### Error Details:

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Is it Razor pages app?  Point 2 means replace or add? Can you please add full `OnGet` method? Or even full `Index.cshtml.cs` file.

Comment: 1 ) I want to render custom html content based on query string value 2) point 2 -> add

Comment: Modify `Index.cshtml`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a misconception how [Razor pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) app works. The actual response is generated by the framework using your model (`Something.cshtml.cs`) and the "view"/"page" (`Something.cshtml`). In the model in corresponding methods you need to load/manage the required data and in the page file you change it's representation via modifying output html.

In case if you try to write the response manually it will cause the aforementioned exception when the framework will try to start the response too.

If you want to add some html to index page - just open `Index.cshtml` and add it somewhere.

Read more:

- [Official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)
- [Learn Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I just changed my index.cs.html to set the content as model and updated  the index.cshtml with model i.e. @Html.Raw(Model.Content)

Comment: @prasadmamidi was good to help! If answer works for you - feel free to mark it as accepted one.